# Bose docking station is not working with new ipod touch

Tags: ipod-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why won't my iPod Touch play in Bose SoundDock speakers anymore?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/why-wont-my-ipod-touch-play-in-bose-sounddock-speakers-anymore)

I just purchased a new ipod touch and it is not working on my bose docking station. Both my daughters have older ipods and they are working. On my new ipod, when it is plugged into the docking station it appears to be playing, when discounected it plays on its own speaker and ear phones... Any ideas what may be the problem?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28294/why-wont-my-iphone-4-play-through-my-bose-sound-dock-anymore and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16552/does-ios-4-break-iphone-compatibility-with-music-docks and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/why-wont-my-ipod-touch-play-in-bose-sounddock-speakers-anymore

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the age of the docking station (is it a Wave?  If so, version 1 or 2?) it may not allow a full range of functions on newer/older iPods etc (depending on the combination - i.e. an old one will not work with new iPods fully, a new one should work with old iPods tho) - this is because they changed the pinouts on the dock connector as part of changing from Firewire to USB.  Basically all iPods used to be Firewire based, then when they became windows compatible they changed to USB, but the dock connector maintained pin options for both, regardless of what was at the other end.  Even with USB iPods, older docks would still allow power to be sent over the Firewire pins for charging the device (as it allowed higher currents, and thus faster charging) - eventually Apple removed this capability, meaning that the dock would appear not to be able to charge your device, but 3rd party hardware manufacturers were too slow to modify their products (even though they had been warned prior to the change to stop using Firewire connections).